# How to redirect on a custom page after login?

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

I'm using `PassportJS` for handle the access to my application, suppose that the user has logged in, and suppose that these urls:

- Login
- Register
- Welcome

need to redirect the user on `dashboard` url, only if the user has logged in, how can I do?

This is my authentication middleware:

```
module.exports = {
    ensureAuthenticated: function(req, res, next){
        if(req.isAuthenticated()){
            return next();
        }

        res.render('index/forbidden');
    }
};
```

Example:

- User go to login
- No session
- Stay on the page

(already works)

- User go to login
- Already logged in
- Redirect to dashboard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create another middleware to redirect if logged in and add it to the routes that don't need login. You are basically doing the opposite.

```
module.exports = {
    ensureAuthenticated: function(req, res, next){
        if(req.isAuthenticated()){
            return next();
        }
        res.render('index/forbidden');
    },
    ensureNOTAuthenticated: function(req, res, next){
        if(req.isAuthenticated()){
            return res.redirect('/dashboard')
        }
        return next();
    }
};
```

For routes that need auth:

```
app.get('/dashboard', ensureAuthenticated, (req,res)=>{...});
```

For routes that dob't need auth:

```
app.get('/login', ensureNOTAuthenticated, (req,res)=>{...});
```